# gradle, setting default resource of library project

Tags: android, gradle, android-resources

I have 2 applications which both rely one one library project. 
The library has strings in different languages.
Application 1 and 2 should have different default languages.
Currently `/res/values/strings.xml` of my library is english.
For Application 2 I need french as default language. How do I set up gradle.conf that it is using `res/values-en` in app1 and `res/values-fr` in app2 as default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible out of the box. You'd have to do some custom code so that you can package your library with one or the other language in the default values folder.